# Cannot find log navigator buttons in Xcode version 3.2.6

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm completely new to the world of Xcode. Since my MacBook is too old for installing the newest Xcode version, I'm trying to learn with Xcode 3.2.6.

Now I go through a book for learning Objective C with Xcode and I have problems to find several buttons. I already needed to let the green "Run"-button view manually via "customize toolbar", but the buttons to have access to the log navigator still do not appear and I don't know how to do it.

That's how my Xcode looks like right now:

[image]

That's what I'm searching:

[image]

How can I view those buttons? Is there another way to access to the log navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 has been a major revision of the software that also made e.g. Interface Builder (a separate program with Xcode 3) or Property List Editor a part of Xcode. The part labeled *Editor Area* with interface elements is a entirely separate program in Xcode 3.

These buttons just don't exist in Xcode 3. Note that the *Run* button just looks like the newer one, the one labeled *Build and Run* (in the middle) does essentially the same thing.

You should either get a machine and OS capable of running Xcode 4, or get older tutorials and documentation specifically for Xcode 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the programs you're writing by going to the folder where you saved the program, and doubleclicking the file in the build / Debug folder.